# Regex C# - get all occurrences in the text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to get all phone numbers from the string, but I get only **first** occurrence. I didn't manage to find anything that will solve my problem here or anywhere else. Please, take a look at my code:

```
List<string> phones = new List<string>();
String test = @"+49 30 12345-67
                        +49 30 1234567
                        +49(30)1234567
                        +49 (30) 12345 - 67
                        +49-30-1234567
                        +49 (0)30 12345-67
                        +49 383 239823
                        +49 (0)42 3298280
                        dkfdklfsjd 393292
                        39239 ";
        const string MatchEmailPattern1 = @"(^\+49)([ \-\(]{1,2}[0-9]{1,6}[ \-\)]{1,2})?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})?";
        var patterns = new string[] { MatchEmailPattern1 };
        Regex r1 = new Regex(string.Join("|", patterns), RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches1 = r1.Matches(test);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Match match in matches1)
        {
            StringBuilder ph = new StringBuilder(match.Value);
            phones.Add(ph.ToString());                
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", phones));
        }
```

Comment: Remove `^` from the pattern.

Comment: Also, put the Console.WriteLine after the foreach

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot.Don't even know how I didn't try removing it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the start of string anchor `^`.  Besides, there is a way to remove some redundant escaping in your character classes.

Use

```
@"(\+49)([- (]{1,2}[0-9]{1,6}[- )]{1,2})?([0-9 ./-]{3,20})?"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%2B49%29%28%5B-%20%28%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C6%7D%5B-%20%29%5D%7B1%2C2%7D%29%3F%28%5B0-9%20.%2F-%5D%7B3%2C20%7D%29%3F&i=%2B49%2030%2012345-67%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49%2030%201234567%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49%2830%291234567%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49%20%2830%29%2012345%20-%2067%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49-30-1234567%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49%20%280%2930%2012345-67%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49%20383%20239823%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B49%20%280%2942%203298280%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dkfdklfsjd%20393292%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2039239%20).

Note that `[- (]` matches a single char, either `-`, a space or a `(`. There is no need to escape `-` at the start (or end) of the character class. Or if you plan to further extend the pattern, keep the hyphen escaped to avoid issues if some other developer adds chars before or after it.

Comment: If you are not using the capture group information, add `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` option when compiling the regex object so that the engine did not have to store the subvalues matched with the capturing groups.